# How To Properly Encode Tweets in Html (with c# hopefully)

Tags: c#, angularjs, twitter

I'm programmatically building up a tweet that end in #angularu which of course blocks the html from that point on. What is the proper way to encode a tweet so that it works and gives the full message in html

```html
<a ng-href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Dan and John Bringing Their  https://angularu.com/ng/session/2015sf/dan-and-john-bringing-their-view-on-the-latest-in-angular Mon 11:00 AM Speakers: Wahlin @DanWahlin, Papa @John_Papa #angularu @AngularU " target="_blank" class="icon-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Dan and John Bringing Their  https://angularu.com/ng/session/2015sf/dan-and-john-bringing-their-view-on-the-latest-in-angular Mon 11:00 AM Speakers: Wahlin @DanWahlin, Papa @John_Papa #angularu @AngularU "></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx):

Your link will render something like this:

```html
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Dan+and+John+blah%23angularu">Tweet</a>
```

For example, using the `UriBuilder`:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(Uri.UriSchemeHttp, "twitter.com", 80, "/home");
builder.Query = "status=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Dan and John are attending #angularU");
var uri = builder.ToString();
```